# Saving SonicWALL NAT Policies settings

Tags: firewall, router, dell, sonicwall

I have a SonicWALL TZ model that I manage.
Now in the [Network] --> [NAT Policies] there are some policies added that have their own checkbox in the [Enabled] column (the other ones have a green checkmark-icon).

Now after a reboot of the sonicwall or after a powerfailure these policies are all reset.
By reset I mean: if policies were checked (=enabled) they are now unchecked. I have to manually check (=enable) them again.

How can I save these settings so that the checkboxes stay checked after reboot or powerfailure if they were checked?
I tried to go to [System] --> [Settings] and clicked [Accept] to persist the settings but I see [Status: There were no changes made.]

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you wait for the page to reload when you check/uncheck a policy.

To make sure a policy is enabled, open the NAT policy in question and verify that "Enabled" is checked at the bottom of the window.

Try rebooting your Sonicwall after that and see if they come back properly.

Comment: Enabled is checked, and when I click [OK] I see at the bottom: "Status: The configuration has been updated.".

But this "configuration", how can this be saved?

Comment: You mean that you want to backup the settings to a file?

Comment: What you have described is what I have already done. They are enabled but for some reason the settings don't stay enabled after reboot or powercycle. It feels like it changed the NAT Policies but that I still need to save the entire configuration. Do you need to save an entire configuration somewhere?  Right uppercorner I'm in [Mode: Configuration], is this ok ?

Comment: Yes, mode configuration is what you want to be. And no there is no "save configuration" button or option. It saves automatically.
When you do save, what feedback do you get at the bottom? (red or green?)

Comment: green: "Status: The configuration has been updated."
this is what I had always, but it doesn't seem to save always, hence the question.

Comment: It looks like you're doing everything right. You might have a failed unit.